# mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.4.7-signed _ Error

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

[logging in but it's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChBwB.png)

I have installed latest version of mongodb. installed well but while running mongod and mongo. I am not getting access for the table. kindly look at the screenshot

Comment: You can ask "kindly" as much as you like, but it would be preferred if you actually paid attention to the warning message when you went to add the picture and then simply copied the "text" from the terminal and pasted that into your question instead. That said, **what error**? Because all I see is a **WARNING** that you have not yet enabled authentication. And that's exactly what happens right after you install.

Comment: How to enable Authentication?

Comment: There is actually a manual. [It might be best if you actually read it.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/). You clearly only just installed. Please take a few days to read and familiarize and try some things. Then come back with any questions as you must, but please actually look for the answers to questions first, because most things have already actually been answered already. Or are indeed well documented.